# WPF textbox that only updates binding when enter is pressed

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox

all.  I have a usercontrol "NumericTextBox" that only allows numeric entries.  I need to exhibit another specialized behaviour, that is, I need it to be able to bind it to a VM value OneWayToSource and only have the VM value update when I press enter while focusing the textbox.  I already have the an EnterPressed event that fires when I press the key, I'm just having a hard time figuring out a way to cause that action to update the binding...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your binding expression, set the UpdateSourceTrigger to Explicit.

```
Text="{Binding ..., UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
```

Then, when handling the EnterPressed event, call UpdateSource on the binding expression, this will push the value from the textbox to the actual bound property.

```
BindingExpression exp = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
exp.UpdateSource();
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a complete version of the idea provided by Anderson Imes:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty UpdateSourceOnKeyProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UpdateSourceOnKey", 
    typeof(Key), typeof(TextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Key.None));

    public static void SetUpdateSourceOnKey(UIElement element, Key value) {
        element.PreviewKeyUp += TextBoxKeyUp;
        element.SetValue(UpdateSourceOnKeyProperty, value);
    }

    static void TextBoxKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {

        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null) return;

        var propertyValue = (Key)textBox.GetValue(UpdateSourceOnKeyProperty);
        if (e.Key != propertyValue) return;

        var bindingExpression = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        if (bindingExpression != null) bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
    }

    public static Key GetUpdateSourceOnKey(UIElement element) {
        return (Key)element.GetValue(UpdateSourceOnKeyProperty);
    }
```

Comment: This is a good start but has a bug. Your attached property can’t be set with a style. To fix, instead of adding the event handler in SetUpdateSourceOnKey function you should pass a callback into FrameworkPropertyMetadata constructor, and subscribe to the event in that callback.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MVVM you can use a combination of decastelijau's approach along with a custom attached property that calls UpdateSource on the textbox when PreviewKeyUp.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty UpdateSourceOnKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
  "UpdateSourceOnKey",
  typeof(Key),
  typeof(TextBox),
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false)
);
public static void SetUpdateSourceOnKey(UIElement element, Key value)
{

  //TODO: wire up specified key down event handler here
  element.SetValue(UpdateSourceOnKey, value);

}
public static Boolean GetUpdateSourceOnKey(UIElement element)
{
  return (Key)element.GetValue(UpdateSourceOnKey);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
<TextBox myprops:UpdaterProps.UpdateSourceOnKey="Enter" ... />
```